# Uninstalling and Reinstalling Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core via NuGet leads to types/namespaces not being found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

After Uninstalling and Reinstalling Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core in the hopes of Intellisense working on an EditorTemplate view that couldn't see @Html, ViewData, etc., I was greeted with a ton of error messages that weren't there previously:

```
The type or namespace name 'Controller' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'ValidateAntiForgeryToken' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and so forth. How do I get it back to where it functions correctly? I've tried Build/Rebuild/Cleaning solution and project to no avail.

What I see in the NuGet section of Dependencies (no flags):

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore (2.0.0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore (1.1.2)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies (1.1.2)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore (1.1.2)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (1.1.2)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core (1.1.3)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles (1.1.2)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (1.1.2)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (1.1.2)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design (1.1.2)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (1.1.1)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets (1.1.2)
Microsoft.Extensions.Extensions.Logging.Debug (1.1.2)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink (1.1.2)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (1.1.1)
```

Comment: Are all your nuget packages installed correctly? Do you see any exclamation marks in your dependency tree?

Comment: Added what I see in the NuGet section (no warnings on the icons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller class is located in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures assembly which is the dependency of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc** package. Just install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc** instead of your current **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core** and it will fix your problem.

Comment: no idea why, but when I looked for it before, it wasn't there, but it was this go around. That solved it